# Flexbox issue on IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I've been trying to solve this issue in the list of IE bugs, but can't seem to find it in there.
It is solved by avoiding the shorthand flex-declaration on the inner element (`.inner`) - `flex: 1`; -> `flex: 1 1 auto;`.

Can you help me please?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  display:flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.inner {
  flex: 1;  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam quidem cum quod, sed iure aspernatur enim nihil vitae eos ullam molestias possimus quia repellat, delectus, rem est quibusdam. Ipsum, perspiciatis.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner">
    lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner">
    lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner">
    lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Actually issue is `Flex items overflowing parent in IE11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue fixed by `flex: 1 0 auto` instead of `flex: 1`